# Unity3d Facebook SDK . How to get users birthday

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

Topic explains my problem. What I have so far :

code for login :

```
FB.Login("public_profile,user_friends,email,publish_actions,user_birthday", LoginCallback);
private void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
         Debug.Log("LoginCallback");
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn == true) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Logged in :)");
            Debug.Log("App-ID :" + FB.AppId);
            Debug.Log("User ID : " + FB.UserId);
            DataHolder.holder.facebookUserID = FB.UserId;

            FB.API("me?fields=name,email,gender,birthday", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, UserDatacallback);

          //  OnLoggedIn();
        }
        else if(FB.IsLoggedIn == false) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Logged In :(");
        }
    }
```

and this is the dataCallback that should handle the responce from FB :

```
private void UserDatacallback(FBResult result)
   {
       IDictionary dict = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as IDictionary;
       DataHolder.holder.facebookUserName = dict["name"].ToString();
       DataHolder.holder.facebookUserEmail = dict["email"].ToString();
       DataHolder.holder.facebookUserGender = dict["gender"].ToString();
       DataHolder.holder.facebookUserBirthday = dict["birthday"].ToString();
       Debug.Log(DataHolder.holder.facebookUserBirthday);


   }
```

Comment: Are you getting an Error After calling UserDataCallback?

Comment: @Aizen Yes I'm getting a null reference since the response I get does not contain a birthday key.

Comment: There  should be a birthday key in there. 2 things comes into my mind with the problem. 1 - the authentication of the FB.API if it is authenticated to get the personal information about the birthday. 2 - the GET method. Have you tried using POST?

Comment: Lastly if you're unsure, why not print `dict` in the console, so you can check all of the key value pair inside it.

Comment: @Aizen I'm possiteve that there is no birthday key in the dict. And what did you mean to use POST. Doesnt POST send data to facebook that I want them to save. Like user scores and stuff ?

Comment: No, POST is a Method of Request. Depends on the API. If the API Request is a POST Method, then you should use POST Method. If it is GET then use Get Method. 

I hope you're not confused with the Keyword GET = Getting Info or POST = Sending INFO, because they do not work like that.

Comment: Are you positive that the user account in question a) has a birthday set and b) the access_token you use has the permission to access user_birthday? If yes, then file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs with all the information (used tokens) and best a sample project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Björn Kaiser This provides access tokesn right ? `FB.Login("public_profile,user_friends,email,publish_actions,user_birthday", LoginCallback);`

Comment: @UriPopov: It should at least ask for access to this data during login. If the user accepts this permission all should be fine and you should get access to it assuming they have a birthday on their profile. Also, if the user is not an admin/developer/tester of the app, this permission requires prior approval from Facebook to be used in a production app (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review)

Comment: @Björn Kaiser, ok I got that. Thank you for the help. I'm just testing the app from unity using the access Token tool from facebook to login. how do I add that permission to the access token, so I can do my tests ?

Comment: IIRC, Unity shows a text field to paste the token, right? In that case, go to the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), select your app from the dropdown, click 'Get Access Token', select all permissions you need, authorize the app and then c&p the token from the Graph API Explorer

Comment: @Björn Kaiser omg thank you. I dont know how but I got really lost in all of this stuff. IMO its not really made clear. Thanks again.